# Error en Java "Qualified new of static class"

Tags: java

Estoy iniciando en la programación en Java, siguiendo las instrucciones de un libro ya algo antiguo, estoy atorado en el tema del uso de la "clase interna static", el código es el siguiente:

```
//fichero ClasesInStatic.java

class A {
  int i=-1;
  static int is=-1;
  public A(int i) {this.i=i;}

  public void printA(Bs unBs) {
     System.out.println("i="+i+" unBs.j="+unBs.j);
  }

  static class Bs{
    int j=2;
    public Bs(int j) {this.j=j;}

    public void printBs(){
       System.out.println(" j="+j+" is="+is);
    }
  }

class ClasesIntLocales {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    A a1 = new A(11), a2 = new A(12);
    println("a1.i="+a1.i+" a2.i="+a2.i);

    // dos formas de crear objetos de la clase interna static
    A.Bs b1 = new A.Bs(-10);
    A.Bs b2 = a1.new Bs(-11);

    println("b1.j="+b1.j+" b2.j="+b2.j);

    b1.printBs();
    b2.printBs();

    a1.printA(b1);
    a1.printA(b2);
  }
}
```

El resultado sugerido debe presentarse de esta manera:

```
a1.i=11 a2.i=12
b1.j=-10 b2.j=-11
j=-10 is=-1
j=-20 is=-1
i=11 unBs.j=-10
i=11 unBs.j=-11
```

Pero presenta el error "Qualifed new of static class" en esta línea:

```
A.Bs b2 = a1.new Bs(-11);
```

Si cambio la declaración a:

```
A.Bs b2 = new A.Bs(-11);
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
a1.i=11 a2.i=12
b1.j=-10 b2.j=-11
j=-10 is=-1
j=-11 is=-1
i=11 unBs.j=-10
i=11 unBs.j=-11
```

El cual es el mismo antes mencionado.

Lo cual me tiene confundido, en cual es la diferencia entre los 
Si elimino la palabra "Static" de la clase "Bs", me permite utilizar la segunda declaración que el libre afirma que funciona, pero tengo que quitar la primera declaración:

```
A.Bs b1 = new A.Bs(-10);
```

Y cambiarla por:

```
A.Bs b1 = a1.new Bs(-11);
```

Además de que pierde el sentido de "clase interna static" y muestra los siguientes datos:

```
a1.i=11 a2.i=12
b1.j=-10 b2.j=-11
j=-10 is=-1
j=-11 is=-1
i=11 unBs.j=-10
i=11 unBs.j=-11
```

Este resultado es el mismo que el anterior, además de tenerme confundido con el uso de las "clases internas locales", ¿si alguien podría explicarlo de forma más extensa o presente un caso práctico de la vida real?

Gracias.

Comment: La pregunta me parece interesante, ¿te parece bien si cambiamos el título a "*¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las clases anidadas y anidadas estáticas?*"?. Creo que daría más visibilidad a la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

En Java hay dos tipos de clases anidadas: las estáticas y las no estáticas.

- Las estáticas *existen* siempre que la clase que las *rodea* exista.
- Las no estáticas *existen* dentro de una instancia de la clase que las *rodea*.

Vamos con un ejemplo básico:

```
class A {

    int valor;

    public A(int v) {
        this.valor = v;
    }

    static int valorGlobal = 42;

    class B {

        // static int x; No se puede!
        final static int x = 24;

        void accion() {
            System.out.println(valor);
            System.out.println(valorGlobal);
        }
    }

    static class C {

        static int x; // Correcto

        void accion() {
            // System.out.println(valor); No tiene acceso a las instancias
            System.out.println(valorGlobal);
        }
    }
}
```

La clase B sólo se puede instanciar en referencia a una instancia de A y tendrán acceso a los atributos estáticos de A y **también a los atributos de la instancia:

```
A ejemplo= new A(5);
A.B b1 = ejemplo.new B();
b1.accion(); //mostrará el valor obtenido de la instancia ejemplo
```

La clase C tiene acceso a los métodos y propiedades estáticos de A, pero por lo demás se comporta como una clase normal, podrías asumir que A es como el *package* de C:

```
A.C ejemplo2= new A.C();
ejemplo2.accion();
```